# Sencha CMD warning Package xxx has unrecognized type ${args.type}

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I have upgraded my sencha CMD to 4.0.0.203 and am now getting this warn

```
Package xxx has unrecognized type ${args.type}
```

what could it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually [Sencha packages](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/3.1.2/#!/guide/command_package_authoring) are created using a "type" variable as "code", "theme" or "locale".

Your question lacks a lot of details to give you a better answer, but I'd bet the error is telling you that your package is missing the "type" configuration somewhere.